# Realtime download optimization. How to find a leak?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using realtime firebase. The problem is that randomly it the graphic shows a high quantity of download on some period of time. The main question is not how to fix it. The main questions are:
1) What is the system of Download from Firebase? How does it work? What are the principles? and the Second question is 2) How to find a leak? 
One more interesting fact is that app was published 17 of February BUT the highest leak was on 3rd of February that means it was while testing. It is basic chat app with profiles of users. Media is only photos. But each user got only 1 photo and total amount in storage so far is only 20mb. The size of the app is less than 50kb. So I don't understand how it is possible to download such amount of data and WHAT DATA WAS DOW
DOWNLOADED to make 5GB.
Below the graphic for 30 days
[image]

Comment: it all depends on what your app does with Firebase and how

Comment: If you have questions about the billing and accounting for your project, Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask.  You should reach out to Firebase support instead.  Even then, without knowing exactly what your app is doing with the data you have in the database, and the usage patterns of your users, it would be impossible to explain why things are different on that one day.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: @GastónSaillén Please write the questions! I am not asking to find the issue. I am asking help to understand how the system of downloading works and what is the good way or maybe tools could find the leak. I am not asking to show me where the issue is

Comment: @DougStevenson please read the answe to mr.Gaston above

Comment: There is nothing we can do here without the information I described.  It is different for each app.  Stack Overflow isn't a place to request links or external references.  It is for programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tools available to figure out where reads are coming from are:

- The Firestore panel in the Firebase console, which you've already found.
- The Firestore panel in the Google Cloud console, which contains some additional information.

Neither of these shows detailed usage information, which is why folks commented on their inability to help. The Firebase support team **may** be able to find additional information, which is why Doug pointed you there.

A few common sources of downloads/reads that developers sometimes don't think of:

1. If you open the database in the Firebase console, any data read there counts towards your quota.
2. If you have a administrative script (for example to update the data while developing) that counts against your quota too.
3. That becomes especially important if you run the administrative script on an interval in a background process.